# IKImageView image not visible while printing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I have `NSSplitView` with two `IKImageView` on both sides to compare them with each other. I'm trying to implement Print functionality but images disappear on preview. ([What should be printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlqmB.png) vs [What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5J9H.png))

What I tried:

Based on [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printapps/osxp_printapps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000861-BAJBFGED), locking focus on `splitView` and directly printing it with

`[[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:view] runOperation];`

But as long as docs state that

> If UI contains multiple views that can have focus view-based printing doesn’t work well.

I tried making a "screenshot"([Method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491919/3423468), [Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3251733/3423468)) of the `splitView`, creating new `viewController` with single `NSImageView`, displaying my screenshot there and then printing imageView. But images weren't visible even in screenshot neither.

Important thing is that printing works just fine if I use `NSImageViews` instead of `IKImageViews`.

What else can I try?(Both `objective-c` and `swift` solutions would work)

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of making a pointer and then assigning an IKImageView object to the print operation method since IKImageView is a subclass of NSView?

Comment: Maybe related: [Is it possible to print IKImageBrowserView In Cocoa programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648544/is-it-possible-to-print-ikimagebrowserview-in-cocoa-programmatically)

Comment: @ElTomato I have two `IKImageViews` placed side by side in `NSSplitView` and I need to print both together.

Comment: @Willeke Tried that but I get an exception in unmanaged code at `img.Draw` call.

Comment: Print a temporary splitview with NSImageViews?

Comment: I was thinking of that exactly but want to try every other possibility before makind a radical decision :d

Comment: @Willeke I did it at last. You can check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a workaround(Also takes into account a zoom level). I get `NSImages` from `IKImageViews`, pass them to new `ViewController` where I show a preview of what will be printed. In that viewcontroller I have a simple `NSView`(rootView) with two `NSImagesViews` side by side. I set my images from `IkImageViews` to `NSImageViews` and then print the rootView.

Here is how I get `NSImages` from `IkImageViews`:

**Steps:**
Get visible/cropped/zoomed rect from `IkImageView`; Create `NSImage` from `IKImageView's` `CGImageRef`; Create new `NSImage` and draw cropped image into it.

> **Note:** obj-c syntax might be a bit wrong, I have never written even a single line of obj-c before(Xamarin Developer).

**Objective-c:**

```
NSRect croppedRect = [imageView convertViewRectToImageRect:[imageView visibleRect]];
NSImage srcImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[imageView image] size:NSZeroSize];
NSImage croppedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:croppedRect.size];
[croppedImage lockFocus];
[srcImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint
          fromRect:croppedRect
          operation:NSCompositeCopy
          fraction:1.0];
[croppedImage unlockFocus];
return croppedImage;
```

**C#(Xamarin):**

```
NSImage GetImageToPrint()
    {
        var cropRect = LeftImage.ConvertViewRectToImageRect(LeftImage.VisibleRect());

        NSImage srcImage = new NSImage(LeftImage.Image, LeftImage.ImageSize);
        NSImage croppedImage = new NSImage(cropRect.Size);
        croppedImage.LockFocus();
        srcImage.Draw(CGPoint.Empty, cropRect, NSCompositingOperation.Copy, 1.0f);
        croppedImage.UnlockFocus();

        return croppedImage;
    }
```

Hope anyone will find the answer useful.

Comment: `[croppedRect lockFocus]` should be [croppedImage lockFocus]?